# "Воробушек" или "воробышек"?

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь

В литературе попадалось "вороб***ы***шек", но чаще говорят "вороб***у***шек". Как все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словари фиксируют оба варианта как правильные.

Answer (score 0):

В книгах и вариант "воробушек" часто встречается:

http://www.google.com/search?hl=ru&tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BA&num=100